# Center a RaisedButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to work out how to center this button.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      home:new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white,),
        body: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[

               new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(

                splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: new Text("Scan",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white),),
                onPressed: scan,
              ),
              new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0), ),
              new Text('$_reader',softWrap: true, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,color: Colors.black),),

         ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is from here: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan#-example-tab-.

Please help me fix this, thanks.

EDIT: How can I center everything in "body"?

Comment: where do you want to center it, horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @Tree I would like to center absolutely everything except the AppBar horizontally.

Comment: Horizontally means everything can be on top (to bottom)? @JP

Comment: @PhucTran What do you mean?

Comment: @JP Just wanted to clarify what you want. Do you want everything is at center of screen?

Comment: @PhucTran Yes like this http://prntscr.com/jk7thj

Comment: Check my answer :) @JP

Comment: Does it work? @JP

Comment: @PhucTran I will test it when I am home

Comment: @JP It should work. I tested it on my phone :)

Comment: @JP I added an edit as an alternate solution based on your picture

Answer (score 6):

You can pass axis alignment in your column

```
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

main axis is vertical axis in column, and cross axis is horizontal.
 It will apply this alignment to all children.

edit:

If you want children to be evenly spaced on vertical axis like you your picture describes, you can use `Expanded`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
          ),
          body: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Container(),),
              new RaisedButton(
                splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: new Text(
                  "Scan",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
              new Text(
                "Reader",
                softWrap: true,
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`mainAxisAlignment`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex/mainAxisAlignment.html) and [`crossAxisAlignment`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html) properties. Or you can wrap `Column` widget using a `Center` widget but this will only centered the cross axis because `Column` is expanded to it's parent, because of that also you have to use `mainAxisAlignment`. There are other elements that you can get benefit, when you want to align childs of `Column`/`Row`, like:

```
//[MainAxisAlignment][1].start
//MainAxisAlignment.center
//MainAxisAlignment.end
//MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround
//MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
//MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
//....
//[CrossAxisAlignment][1].baseline
//CrossAxisAlignment.start
//CrossAxisAlignment.center
//CrossAxisAlignment.end
//CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

Another thing is, I saw you have used `Padding` widget to add margin between `RaisedButton` widget and `Text` widget. `Padding` is also just a widget like `Container`. So, instead `Padding` you can simply use `Container` or `SizedBox` with some `height` to get margin between.

Simple example:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text("Click"),
      onPressed: (){},
    ),
    Container(height: 20.0),//SizedBox(height: 20.0),
    new Text('Hello'),
  ],
),
```

### Update:

**Since you are directly adding to the `Scaffold` body, Wrapp `Column` using a `Center` widget** and remove the `crossAxisAlignment`. This must work.

If, you try my code example(with `Container`), you dont have to wrap using a `Center` widget because I didn't add `width` for that `Container`.

Comment: How can I just tell it to center everything horizontally?

Adding 

`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

to 

`body: new Column(`

does not work.

Comment: @JP Sorry, I didnt notice that you are directly added Column to the Scaffold body. See updated section

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Column in a Center AND set **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,** to the Column. Check below code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
            splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: new Text(
              "Scan",
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          ),
          new Text(
            "Reader",
            softWrap: true,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it body in **new Container()** for horizontal center, for vertical center uncomment  mainAxisAlignment: ***MainAxisAlignment.center, and crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,*** in Column inside Center.

```cs
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(

      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      home:new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white,),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

               new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(

                splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: new Text("Scan",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white),),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
              new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0), ),
              new Text('_reader',softWrap: true, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,color: Colors.black),),

         ],
         ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

3 things needed

1. Container
2. mainAxisAlignment
3. crossAxisAlignment

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: new Text(
                  "Scan",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              ),
              new Text(
                'Some random text',
                softWrap: true,
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a working code that I have put here. I wonder which pic down-voted this even with out commenting why he/she did so.